# Is there any way to turn a Windows 8.1 Core into Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8.1, migration, license-key

I just installed a Windows 8 licence on a PC (and then I upgraded it to Windows 8.1 Core). I have already installed all the important application by talking with IT. Some application license required an IT guy to be connected remotely to the PC for doing it (not free charge)

So, when I almost finished, I realized that one application needs Windows 8.1 to work properly.

I just need to convert Windows 8.1 Core in Windows 8.1 Pro.

I know there is an upgrade to turn **Windows 8.1 Core** to **Windows 8.1 Pro**, but It is too expensive. I would like to buy a **Windows 8.1 Pro** license and use it in this PC and to reuse the **Windows 8.1 Core** license in another pc.

Comment: Do you need to upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 8 Pro, like the title of your question asks, or do you need to upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and in the process change the license key, like the body of your questiuon seems to ask? The answer is probably to look up "Windows anytime upgrade".

Comment: Your question is highly confusing.  If you need to add "Pro" to your existing Windows 8 version use ["Add Features"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/feature-packs). Otherwise, please edit your question and clarify exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you saying you have windows 8 on one machine, and upgraded it to windows 8.1, then you want to remove the windows 8 license from that PC, and install it onto another pc, then upgrade to windows 8.1 on that other pc? (if so then you only have one windows 8 license not 2, and windows 8.1 is a free upgrade to windows 8) - Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: I need to convert windows 8.1 in windows 8.1 pro

Comment: That is not free unfortunately - you need the pro-pack upgrade. Here is a link to buy it on Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-8-1-Pack-Upgrade/dp/B00EDSI7K0#

Comment: The "Pro Pack" is the only way to change `Windows 8.x Core` to `Windows 8.x Professional` ( actually `Professional w/ Media Center` ).  This rule applies to 8.0 and 8.1

Comment: I knew that by I have to avoid the upgrades, It would be cheaper to buy a Windows 8.1 Pro licence and install in the pc.

Comment: Well, what's stopping you from buying regular Windows 8.1 Pro license and installing it?

Comment: Time and Money? Time for reinstall all the applications, and the money that other companies charges for install some of them.

Comment: @JCalcines - Does not matter.  You asked how to do this, we have told you, the only legal way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to buy a Windows 8.1 Pro license and use it in this PC
>   and to reuse the Windows 8.1 Core license in another pc.

This is a very simple process, documented [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/feature-packs):

> Add Windows 8.1 Pro Pack or Windows 8.1 Media Center Pack to your
>   edition of Windows 8.1
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search.  (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, and then click Search.)
> 2. Enter add features in the search box, and then tap or click Settings.
> 3. Tap or click Add features to Windows 8.1 and then do one of the following:
>
>    • If you need to purchase a product key, tap or click I want to buy a
>      product key online. Follow the steps to purchase and enter a product key.
>
>    • **If you already have a product key, tap or click I already have a
>      product key**.
> 4. Enter your product key and click Next.
> 5. Read the license terms, select the check box to accept the license terms, and then click Add features.

I have done this before. As product key you supply the key of your Windows Pro license. It's very quick and clean, no reinstall required. But I haven't reused the non-Pro licenses. Legally you can use them (unless they are preinstalled OEM licenses tied to the machine), worst case there will be a phone call with MS support involved.

Comment: This option should work, but It doesn't work with an OEM key (It seems pretty obvious). So, the solution is reinstall everything. Nevertheless, I marked your answer as a solution because in a standard case I'm sure that it works.

Comment: @JCalcines - What makes you think it doesn't work with an OEM license?  **I promise you it does**  I promise you Microsoft wouldn't want to exclude potential revenue.

Comment: @JCalcines I've done this to upgrade OEM licenses to Pro licenses. But the Pro licenses weren't OEM licenses themselves - is that what you mean?

Comment: @peter Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Both licenses were OEM.